# cuda - Zero-copy memory, memory-mapped file

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, cuda, mmap

I am trying to create a mapped memory file, containing `uint32_t`s, and then use that as zero-copy pinned memory as shown below for CUDA. I am getting the `cudaErrorInvalidValue` when getting the device pointer, having allocated space and mapped the memory from file. I know the error message (from the API) means :

> This indicates that one or more of the parameters passed to the API call is not within an acceptable range of values.

But I'm struggling to figure out why I'm having this problem.... Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

    …

int main(void) 
{
  struct stat buf;

    …

  uint32_t *data, *dev_data;

  cudaDeviceProp cuda_prop;
  cudaGetDeviceProperties(&cuda_prop, 0);
  if (!cuda_prop.canMapHostMemory) 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);


  int data_file = open(data_file_name, O_RDONLY);
  int stat = fstat(sa_file, &buf);
  int data_file_size = buf.st_size;

  err = cudaHostAlloc((void**)&data, data_file_size, cudaHostAllocMapped);
  if (err == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  data = (uint32_t*) mmap(0, data_file_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, data_file, 0);

  err = cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&dev_data, (void*)data, 0);
  if (err == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation)
  {
    printf("cudaHostGetDevicePointer - Mem Alloc Err\n"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (err == cudaErrorInvalidValue) //ERROR HERE.
  {
    printf("cudaHostGetDevicePointer - Invalid Val Err\n"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

    …

}
```

Comment: `cudaHostAlloc` assigned a value to `data`, and then you overwrote that value with your `data = mmap(...)` line.  `cudaHostGetDevicePointer` has no idea what to do with the new value of `data` provided by `mmap` since that value was not provided by the CUDA API.  You could try getting rid of the `cudaHostAlloc` line, and then do a `cudaHostRegister` on `data` after the `mmap` line.   I don't know if that will work or not.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the GPU driver could register a virtual allocation from a mmaped file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that the logical sequence of your program is incorrect.  This line assigns a value to `data` provided by the CUDA API:

```
err = cudaHostAlloc((void**)&data, data_file_size, cudaHostAllocMapped);
```

This line then *overwrites* that value, with a new one:

```
data = (uint32_t*) mmap(0, data_file_size, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, data_file, 0);
```

At that point, the value of `data` is not recognized by the CUDA API as being a pinned memory space anymore, so when you call this:

```
err = cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&dev_data, (void*)data, 0);
```

you get an error, because the value contained in `data` is not recognized.

**EDIT:** (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44569936/registering-mapped-linux-kernel-character-device-memory-with-cudahostregister-re))
Apart from that issue, it seems that if you change the file handling from read-only, to read-write, then this process can be made to work (throws no runtime errors).  Here's a complete code (which doesn't contain the above logical flaw) that demonstrates this (I have previously created a `test.dat` file of size 566316 bytes):

```
$ cat t706.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
  struct stat buf;

  char *dev_data;

  cudaDeviceProp cuda_prop;
  cudaGetDeviceProperties(&cuda_prop, 0);
  if (!cuda_prop.canMapHostMemory)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);


  int data_file = open("test.dat", O_RDWR);
  int stat = fstat(data_file, &buf);
  int data_file_size = buf.st_size;
  printf("data_file_size = %d\n", data_file_size);
  char *data = (char *) mmap(0, data_file_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, data_file, 0);
  if (data == MAP_FAILED) {
    printf("mmap failure\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}
  cudaError_t err = cudaHostRegister(data, data_file_size, cudaHostRegisterDefault);
  if (err != cudaSuccess) { //ERROR HERE.
    printf("cudaHostRegister fail\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

  err = cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&dev_data, (void*)data, 0);
  if (err == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation)
  {
    printf("cudaHostGetDevicePointer - Mem Alloc Err\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if (err == cudaErrorInvalidValue)
  {
    printf("cudaHostGetDevicePointer - Invalid Val Err\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -o t706 t706.cu
$ ./t706
data_file_size = 566316
$
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, and for correcting the host allocation logic! I suppose the easiest way around this is probably `fread`ing instead of using `mmap`...

Comment: Passing the flag `cudaHostRegisterReadOnly` to `cudaHostRegister()` allows the memory to be mapped without needing to be marked `PROT_WRITE`. This not only makes the coded cleaner, it also appears to confer a decent speed bump, at least in my test setup.