# Python - Loading files into memory using CUDA?

Tags: python, cuda, deep-learning, gpu, data-science

I recently learnt about CUDA programming in python and I was wondering if there was a way to load files into memory faster using GPU. I'm particularly trying to find a way to load ML datasets faster. Till now, I've been using the `multiprocessing` library

Comment: GPUs don't support any sort of file I/O, so no.

Comment: @talonmies is this possible: memory mapped file, pinned gpu buffer(using pointer of memory map) and directly reading from CUDA workitems. Would it decrease number of I/O so it is faster? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518875/cuda-zero-copy-memory-memory-mapped-file

Comment: Using `mmap` isn't the same thing as performing file system I/O on the GPU. Especially in Python where everything runs in a single host thread

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do memmap in python with cuda?