# Fast write Pytorch CUDA tensors to memory mapped files on GPU

Tags: python, memory-management, gpu, pytorch, memory-mapped-files

I saw that is possible to use CUDA to write to memory mapped files (reference [cuda - Zero-copy memory, memory-mapped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518875/cuda-zero-copy-memory-memory-mapped-file) )

I am wonder if it is somehow possible in Pytorch to write a cuda mounted tensor directory to a mem mapped stored on GPU.

The purpose of this is to speed up writing tensors after each training step. Currently,

```
with torch.no_grad():
    numpyMemmap[arrayOfRandomIndexes] = u_embeddings.weight.data.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

takes 6 seconds. I think it’s because the numpy memory map is stored on CPU. I need something that would write in a fraction of a second since I will be storing the tensors after each training step, and there will be hundreds of thousands of training steps.